# For Loop is not iterating for a third time? (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

**Question:** Why is my for loop not iterating for the third time?

**What I noticed:** In the for loop statement below, removing the if-else statement allowed me to print i from 0-2 and the "1" three times.

```
for (size_t i {0}; i < user_input.length(); ++i) {
        
        cout << i << endl;
        cout << user_input.length() << endl;
        
        string the_spaces;
        string the_line;

        for (size_t b {i}; b < (user_input.length() - 1); ++b) {
            the_spaces += " ";
        }

        for (size_t k {0}, y {i+1}; k < y; ++k) {
            the_line += user_input[k];
        }
        
        if (i >= 1) {
            cout << "Bob";
            for (size_t z {i - 1}; z >= 0; --z) {
                the_line += user_input[z];
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Beb" << endl;
        }
        
        cout << "1" << endl;
            
    }
```

---

```
Output:

0                   // i
3                   // the user_input.length
Beb                 // output from if-else
1                   // 1 printed at the end of the for loop expression
1                   // i (2nd iteration)
3                   // the user input.length
```

the code ends here... Neither printing Beb or Bob, as well as, the "1" from **cout << "1" << endl;** on the 2nd & 3rd iteration.

Comment: `for (size_t z {i - 1}; z >= 0; --z)` is infinite loop.

Comment: This should be the perfect time to learn how to *debug* your programs. For example, with a *debugger* you can step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Shouldn't even need a debugger - just turn on (all) compiler warnings: any sane one will warn you that `z >= 0` is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z >= 0` is always `true` since `z` is an `unsigned` type.

Your program therefore loops. Although there are other solutions, using a `long long` rather than a `std::size_t` as the loop index is probably the simplest.

---

`b < (user_input.length() - 1)` is also problematic if `user_input` is empty. Use

```
b + 1 < user_input.length()
```

instead.

Comment: Allow me to add one suggestion: ``std::ptrdiff_t`` would also be appropriate for ``z``. (The standard states: "std::ptrdiff_t is used for pointer arithmetic and array indexing, if negative values are possible." This perfectly matches this use case).

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich: Yes, that's not a bad one. Why not submit an answer? Stack Overflow works best when there are a selection to choose from. I think though I'd prefer something based around `std::make_signed`. Personally I use `-->` (slide operator) when counting backwards with an unsigned type, thereby not messing about with the type at all, but it's fallen out of fashion.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop:

```
for (size_t z {i - 1}; z >= 0; --z) {
    the_line += user_input[z];
}
```

because `size_t` will never be negative, so `z >= 0` will always true. So this is an infinite loop.

You can typecast it:

```
for (long long z {static_cast<long long>(i - 1)}; z >= 0; --z) {
    the_line += user_input[z];
}
```

or if you don't want t typecast it, you can use this rather odd way:

```
for (size_t z{i}; z-- > 0; )
    the_line += user_input[z];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing. The "rather odd way" is how I'd do it, although I like to write `z --> 0` as I feel it better expresses the idiom.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'll use my rather odd way as well. It's interesting that you call it the slide operator while I call it the [downto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c#comment119493280_1642035) operator. Maybe it differs between C++ standards

Comment: Folk listening in would be horrified at our thinking the C++ standard cares to mention it. It's not really an operator at all of course. I started using it in my C days at university.

Comment: @Bathsheba That looks a bit weird. Most sane coding conventions/design rules prescribe that postfix operators should appear directly after the variable, and that there should be spaces between the comparison operator and its operands. "It looks funny" is not a good reason to break well-established conventions.

Comment: @Alderath: Yes it does look weird on first inspection. But then bearing in mind that unsigned subtraction is not closed, `--` is a weird thing to do to an unsigned type. Yes I guess it's down to fashion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/4117728

Answer (score 0):

One addition to the answers already given: Another C++ standard conform and highly portable signed type appropriate for `z` is `std::ptrdiff_t`. (It is similar to POSIX's `ssize_t`.)

(Quoting from the standard: "`std::ptrdiff_t` is used for pointer arithmetic and array indexing, if negative values are possible.")